# kubernetes containers don't have internet connectivity

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-ec2

I have ran a deployment of three nginx pods as show here below:

```
ubuntu@k8s-t2-cp:~$ kubectl get pod -o wide
NAME                               READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE     IP               NODE              NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
nginx-deployment-55f598f8d-6d25c   1/1     Running   0          7h42m   192.168.26.152   ip-172-30-1-183   <none>           <none>
nginx-deployment-55f598f8d-6j92r   1/1     Running   0          7h42m   192.168.26.151   ip-172-30-1-183   <none>           <none>
nginx-deployment-55f598f8d-rhpwv   1/1     Running   0          7h42m   192.168.26.150   ip-172-30-1-183   <none>           <none>
```

When I am attached inside one of the pods, I am unable to run an 'apt update' or 'curl ifconfig.me' as the pod doesn't appear to have internet connectivity.  I am new to kubernetes so is there a way to setup internet connectivity on the pods?

Here is the deployment yaml file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 6
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: nginx-deployment
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: nginx-deployment
    spec:
      hostNetwork: false
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirstWithHostNet
      containers:
        - name: nginx
          image: nginx
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
          - containerPort: 80
```

My AWS security groups are fully permissive on both the cluster node and the worker node.  I have an allow all on both incoming and outgoing.

Comment: could you share more details? how did you create this deployment?, how looks your AWS security groups...

Comment: @clay I have answered your questions in an edit above.